# What does the Bigquery error "Your project exceeded quota for free storage for projects" mean?

Tags: google-bigquery, limit

We've started to get an error while querying

```
error = {
  "location":"free.storage",
  "message":"Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free storage for projects. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
  "reason":"quotaExceeded"
})
```

But I can't find any info about "quota for free storage"

What exactly is this quota about?

Comment: Click that link, and search the page for `quotaExceeded`. "This error returns when your project exceeds a BigQuery quota, a custom quota, or when you haven't set up billing and exceed the free tier for queries." The text "free tier for queries" even links directly to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I've got "free storage for projects" not "free tier for queries"

Comment: You should **read the pages Google is linking you to**. The pricing link takes you directly to a section titled "Always free usage limits" which specifically mentions **storage**. "BigQuery ML models and training data stored in BigQuery are included in the BigQuery storage free tier. The first 10 GB per month is free."

Comment: It's a more reasonable question than it may appear. I ran into this as well, even though I have nowhere near the stated storage limits and have barely used the project recently. A good answer to this question would help clarify what applies to the storage limit, how it is calculated, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is clear -- you're approaching the limits of the free quota, likely because you are working in the [bigquery sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox) without a billing account configured.

Thus, you are subject to the [free tier limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free-tier), in particular, 10 GB of active storage and 1TB of processing for queries.

Google has a guide for [upgrading from the sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox) but the key will be to enable billing for your account so that you can access more storage.

Comment: By the way, if I delete all tables, the error will disappear? Or it counts all data during the month?

Comment: Personally I deleted everything other than my tables (which have 1 and 2 rows respectively) and also deleted all my Cloud Storage contents since I wasn't using them anyway, and I still get the error.